# React Material UI - Make Slider update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a multi-step form (survey) with React.js and [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) components library.
At the step with a slider, the  component doesn't update the state. I was trying to set value with setValue from React.useState() and other various methods. Didn't work out. Does anybody know what the problem is? I'm stuck.

Here is the link to Codesandox: [project's code](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-tesla-48655?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Code of the Slider component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Slider, Input } from '@material-ui/core/';


export default function DiscreteSlider({ values, handleChange }) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(values.areaSpace);

  const handleSliderChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value === '' ? '' : Number(event.target.value));
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    if (value < 0) {
      setValue(0);
    } else if (value > 100) {
      setValue(100);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div onChange={handleChange('areaSpace')} style={{marginTop: '20px', marginBottom: '20px'}}>
      <Input
        value={value}
        margin="dense"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        inputProps={{
          step: 1,
          min: 0,
          max: 800,
          type: 'number',
          'aria-labelledby': 'input-slider',
        }}
      />
      <Slider
        style={{marginTop: '20px'}}
        value={typeof value === 'number' ? value : 0}
        onChange={handleSliderChange}
        aria-labelledby="input-slider"
        step={1}
        min={0}
        max={800}
        onChangeCommitted={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. Also, when providing a code sandbox, fork the sandbox after putting the link in your question so that further changes to the sandbox do not break the sandbox provided in your question (right now it is broken).

Comment: It looks like you have it working now. Are you still having a problem or not?

Comment: @RyanCogswell I just update the Codesandbox link to a working version of the app. Yes, still has the problem

Comment: Please describe the steps to reproduce the problem and what it currently does versus what you want it to do. Right now when I go to the step with the Slider it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Slider works fine, but when you drag it, the value of an input changes, but not going to the state, only if you type it into an input box.

Comment: But the input changes **because** of the change to state. What leads you to believe that it is "not going to the state"?

Comment: @RyanCogswell When testing it  with React Dev tools and on Confirm step you have initial state (Areaspace : 40)

Comment: The confusing aspect of your question is that you have state at multiple levels. The state inside your `Slider` component is updating just fine and the code in your question text doesn't show any of `MainForm.js` where the state that isn't getting updated resides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your `Slider` you have the following:

```
        onChangeCommitted={handleChange}
```

The `handleChange` above is being passed from `MainForm.js` which defines it as:

```
  // Handle inputs change
  handleChange = input => event => {
    this.setState({ [input]: event.target.value });
  }
```

When that function gets called, all it is going to do is return another function. You need to call `handleChange("areaSpace")` in order to get a function that will then try to set the "areaSpace" state when it is called. Another problem is that the change function is getting the value from `event.target.value`, but for the Slider the value is passed as a second parameter.

The following code addresses both of these issues:

```
        onChangeCommitted={(event, value) =>
          handleChange("areaSpace")({ target: { value } })
        }
```

[image: Edit Propagate Slider state to main form]

There are more elegant ways of dealing with this, but the above fixes the problem without changing any other layers. It does still leave another problem which is that if you change the input instead of the Slider, the `areaSpace` state won't be updated, but I'll leave that as a problem for you to work through.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I've tried your solution and its working as I wanted to. Huge thanks!

Comment: @RyanCogswell I was trying to add slider element to my already custom form library. But I couldn't get it to work. Thanks to you, now I know that onChange of slider doesn't pass value in the `event.target.value` but as a second argument. The problem is, I already have a working code to handle onChange and I don't want to change it. I don't know why the slider is passing the new value as a second argument instead of in the event. Do you know any way I can get the new value without adding another parameter to my handleChange function?

Comment: @RyanCogswell I got it to work by using a hacky method of ```onChange = {(event, value) => {event.target.value = value; changeHandler(elemName, event);}}```. But if there is a better or more elegant approach as you mentioned, I would certainly like to know.